# Building a table of "Likes for feedbacks", SQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, hibernate

Im building a new table related to my feedback feature.
My backend build with Java, spring boot, Im using hibernate. The question is if to insert column of ID or WITHOUT?
Because I have an ID and hibernate knows what he is looking..

```
CREATE TABLE feedback_helpful (
user_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
comment_id BIGINT NOT NULL,
timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NOW(),
FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
FOREIGN KEY(comment_id) REFERENCES feedback_comment_public(id),
PRIMARY KEY(user_id, comment_id)
);
```

The question is if will it afect on the speed? The binding models from the DB will be faster? What is the best way to build it?

Thanks

Comment: Asking for the "best way" is almost always opinion-based. --- The question might be better suited for [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/). --- Assuming that this table is used to get all users that upvoted a comment or all comments a user upvoted, the schema looks good to me (classic join table).

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no such thing "the best way" :)
for each comment, we can see the button "Helpful" and users can like this comment, so the BE is supposed to send all the likes about this comment, and there are more comments below, so it will send also all the likes for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case 1:  Many users upvoting many comments -- a classic "many-to-many" relationship.  *There is one best way*

```
-- no id
PRIMARY KEY(comment_id, user_who_upvoted)
INDEX(user_who_upvoted, comment_id)
```

One index makes one direction efficient; the other takes care of the other direction.

Case 2:  (This is where the "user_id" wrote the "comment".)

Since you have a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY(user_id, comment_id)`, there is no need to add an artificial ID.

Although this looks like a "many-to-many" mapping table, I don't think it really is.  I expect that one 'user' can have many 'comments'.  But can one 'comment' have many 'users'?

If not, then it is really a "1-to-many" relationship.  Such a relationship should *not* be implemented with an extra table.  Instead

- `users` has no mention of the comment
- `comments` -- each row has the `user_id` that it relates to.
- `comments` probably needs `PRIMARY KEY(comment_id), INDEX(user_id)`.
- `comment_id is` AUTO_INCREMENT` and is probably used only for providing a unique key for that table.  (It is unlikely to have a 'natural' PK.)
- If you are frequently fetching all the comments for one user, then this is slightly better than the indexing suggestion above:

  ```
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id, comment_id),  -- for efficient access
  INDEX(comment_id)  -- to keep auto_increment happy
  ```

Comment: OK, so this is from DB perspective.. 
BUT, what about spring boot perspective?
I want to make a model to make my life easier, so not just binding a table, got my point?

Comment: @ChenCohen - When the dataset becomes big, you must learn not just the framework (Spring) or the database (MySQL), but _both_.  Frameworks are a crutch to get you started; they rarely scale to huge datasets.